# d3 date histogram from elasticsearch output

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm following the tutorial on d3 date histograms from http://bl.ocks.org/sbrudz/ed6454e3d25640d19a41

I've created a quick JSfiddle that shows where I am https://jsfiddle.net/esns05vf/ and the code is also below.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.bar {
    fill: steelblue;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script>

var myvis = [{
          "key_as_string": "01-05-2015",
          "key": 1430438400000,
          "doc_count": 186
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "01-06-2015",
          "key": 1433116800000,
          "doc_count": 23
        }]


</script>


<body>


<script>

//New chart
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y").parse;
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%m-%y");
var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").tickFormat(formatDate);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(6);

var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


//go through my vis and run parseDate on each of the key_as_string dates 
myvis.forEach(function (d) {
    d.f = parseDate(d.key_as_string);
});


//Get the date range from d.f that contains the output of parseDate
var monthExtent = d3.extent(myvis, function (d) {return d.f;})

//Create one bin per month
var monthBins = d3.time.months(d3.time.month.offset(monthExtent[0], -1),
                                d3.time.month.offset(monthExtent[1], 1));

//Use the date historgram
var binByMonth = d3.layout.histogram()
    .value(function (d) { return d.f; })
    .bins(monthBins);

var histData = binByMonth(myvis);


//Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(monthBins));
y.domain([0, d3.max(histData, function (d) { return d.y; })]);

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(histData)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.x) ; })
    .attr("width", function (d) { return x(new Date(d.x.getTime() + d.dx))-x(d.x)-1 ;})
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
    .attr("height", function (d){ return height - y(d.y); })

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("number of docs")


</script>



<div>
    <p> Date histogram </p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the tutorial they have the data source as an external file and my data source is the JSON response from elasticsearch. I've added the elasticsearch response in a variable to the JSfiddle.

I would be expecting to see two bars of different heights and also for the y axis to run from 0 to whatever the maximum doc_count value is, not 0 to 1 as it currently does.

The tutorial does some sort of count over the number of records that match a particular date range. In my data, I already have a count returned by elasticsearch, so I dont need to do another count.

How can I get my data to render correctly. I'm sure that it something far less complicated than the tutorial is trying to explain, but I am very new to D3 so any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a barchart not a histogram. Good tutorial here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/

Comment: Thanks, that is what I started with, however as the chart will update depending on a users query, (the users query may return 0 to 1000's of aggregation buckets from elasticsearch) I was trying have d3 put the data that is returned from elasticsearch into its own bins (buckets), so that the data always fits on the graph in a way that the user can make sense of it. Do you still think barchart would be the better option. I was hoping to achieve something similar to kibana's time line view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at this example instead (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304), because as you said, yours is counting the number of record per month

I did a fiddle with your example data set 
 https://jsfiddle.net/duck4wmy/

```
var data = [{
          "key_as_string": "01-05-2015",
          "key": 1430438400000,
          "doc_count": 186
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "01-06-2015",
          "key": 1433116800000,
          "doc_count": 23
        }]
```

Comment: Also is this section actually doing anything? function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
} Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought.